# GridView affected by window.open

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridView which works nicely until I open a new window by clicking a button. When the new window is opened the values in one of the columns 'lblTotalPrice' gets erased. 'lblTotalPrice' is a template field, which is calculated in MealList_RowDataBound (quantity * price). The footer for the column, however is not affected when the new window is opened (also gets its value in MealList_RowDataBound).

Also the font-size of the data-bound columns are changed when the new window is opened.

Any ideas of what might cause this? When stepping through the code there are no other lines executed after btnEnvComment_Click

When gridView is databound again, everything is back to normal.

The gridView:

```
        <rwg:BulkEditGridView ID="MealList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="4"
            BackColor="White"  DataKeyNames="ItemId,ProductId" SaveButtonID="SaveButton"
            DataSourceID="SqlMealItems" style="float:left"
            OnRowDataBound="MealList_RowDataBound"  OnRowCreated="MealList_RowCreated" CssClass="gridView">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="MealListItemAlt" BackColor="#a6dbed" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" HeaderText="Prod #" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ReadOnly="True" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Namn" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Antal"  ControlStyle-CssClass="numeric" >
                    <ControlStyle CssClass="numeric" Width="30px"></ControlStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enhet">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownUnit" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownUnit_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="False" runat="server" DataTextField="Unit"  DataValueField="Unit">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle Width="70px" />
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="á pris" ReadOnly="True"  ControlStyle-CssClass="rightAlign"  ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                    <ControlStyle CssClass="numeric" ></ControlStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="80px" />
               </asp:BoundField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Totalt"  ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat = server></asp:label>               
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="80px" />
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPricePerMeal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Bold="true" Font-Overline="True" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit" HeaderText="h"  ReadOnly="True" />
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:image runat="server" ID="imgBlob" Width="24"></asp:image>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 
               <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 
           </Columns>
           <FooterStyle CssClass="MealListFooter" />
           <HeaderStyle CssClass="MealListHead" />
        </rwg:BulkEditGridView>
```

The code for the button that open the new window:

```
    protected void btnEnvComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int offsetPos = 125;  // set placement of new window
        String URL = "EnvComment.aspx?MealID=" + Session["MealId"];
        String responsCommand = "window.open('" + URL + "','_blank','height=400,width=300,top=" + ",left=" + offsetPos.ToString() + offsetPos.ToString() + ",titlebar=1')";
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write(responsCommand);
        Response.Write("</script>");
    }
```

Comment: your `RowDataBound` event will be called each time the page does a `Postback`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how that information will help me. 
If I trigger a postback from code behind e.g. in the end of btnEnvComment, the behavior is still the same.

Comment: If your value of `lblTotalPrice` is only set in `RowDataBound` then that is the place you need to check. what is postback from code behind?

Comment: in my view, can you try button click event as client side instead of server side? write the same logic in client.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad - lblTotalPrice is only manipulated in RowDataBound and DropDownUnit_SelectedIndexChanged. None of these are triggered by the btnEnvComment. That is why I don't understand how the values can be cleared.

Comment: I didn't realize that the page was re-loaded when I clicked btnEnvComment. This caused the grid to have been refreshed without RowDataBound having been triggered. Thus, no values in lblTotalPrice.

Still font size and size of textbox in gridView is different than before clicking `btnEnvComment`, though.